Vnc server/viewer - everything is to small
Using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS both on laptop and on kvm guest. Also using tigervnc server, and tigervnc vncviewer.
When I use vncviewer to go into my kvm guest, everything is smaller. In the screen shot below, the left is my vncviewer session. On the right is my native linux laptop.
I start the vncserver session with vncserver -localhost -fg -autokill -rfbport xxxx.
I have tried using randr to change the resolution and dpi, but it does not make a difference. Also, changing the geometry of the viewer window does not make a difference.
This is only a issue on my laptop. This is not a issue when I use the viewer on my linux desktop PC.
I would rather not have to mess with the xterm font settings and chrome setting individually.  How can I change the viewer or vnc server to where everything is bigger?


Did you try vncserver -dpi 120 -localhost -fg -autokill -rfbport xxxx or can you open a menu bar if connected and try to set scaling there?
